# CLFormRowDescriptor doesn't connect to a view controller

Tags: swift, xlform

I am trying to connect a `CLFormRowDescriptor` to a view controller in this way:

```
    var form = XLFormDescriptor()

    var section : XLFormSectionDescriptor
    var row : XLFormRowDescriptor

    form = XLFormDescriptor(title: "ABC") as XLFormDescriptor

    section = XLFormSectionDescriptor.formSectionWithTitle("Bla bla") as XLFormSectionDescriptor
    form.addFormSection(section)

    row = XLFormRowDescriptor(tag: "bla", rowType: XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorPush, title: "BlaBla");
    row.action.viewControllerStoryboardId = "test";
    section.addFormRow(row)
```

And the view controller Storyboard ID is `test`.
When I run the application, I get the following error message:

> 2015-07-03 16:42:24.022 TestTest[1001:203160] ***
>
> Assertion failure in -[XLFormSelectorCell formDescriptorCellDidSelectedWithFormController:], /Users/valec/Developer/TestTest/ios/Pods/XLForm/XLForm/XL/Cell/XLFormSelectorCell.m:166
>
> 2015-07-03 16:42:24.024 TestTest[1001:203160] ***
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'rowDescriptor.action.viewControllerClass must conform to XLFormRowDescriptorViewController protocol'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x18246c2d8 0x1941400e4 0x18246c198 0x183320ed4 0x100387a5c 0x100398680 0x10039c6d0 0x18700d408 0x1870c7724 0x186f681d4 0x186ed8680 0x1824242a4 0x182421230 0x182421610 0x18234d2d4 0x18bda36fc 0x186f4af40 0x100028e8c 0x1947eaa08)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Do you have an idea on how to solve this problem? Do you need any further code or info?

Answer (score 0):

Since your row type is `XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorPush` XLForm infers that you want to implement a custom selector and tries to pass the row descriptor (that contains the current selected value) to the selector view controller (in your case the view controller which "test" as storyboard id ).

Make "test" view controller conforms to `XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorPush` to fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok I see the problem: it doesn't know which value to pass to the row. In my case, I just don't want to pass any value, it should only connect to another page when clicking on the row...how can I do that?